# Disable mousewheel on HTML and exclude a specific div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable mousewheel on HTML, and exclude a specific element from this rule.

I am using the following code:

```
$('html').bind("mousewheel, touchmove", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$('.exclude').unbind("mousewheel, touchmove");
```

Mouse Wheel does not work on the `exclude` element either.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `off()` method of jQuery

Like this

```
$(".exclude").off("mousewheel, touchmove");
```

The unbind() method was deprecated in version 3.0. Use the off() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

with following code you can disable mousewheel on document

```
 window.onwheel = e => e.preventDefault = false;
```

but i think it is impossible to allow only an child element to wheel.

Try to use css

```
overflow:hidden;
```

and

```
overflow:auto;
```

for the elements you will allowed to scroll